# C++ Detect If Function Has Been Hooked (32bit Machine)

Tags: c++, security, memory, byte

When people hook a function in general they modify the first few instructions of the function they want to hook with branch instructions to where they want to do some stuff then branch back to original function and restore it, the problem with that is that literally nothing is safe. Any value you are trying to hide can easily be found (these values can be found many other ways than just function hooking, but that's all i'm focusing on in this question)

Let's say you go through the effort of implementing a hash algorithm like MD5 into your C++ application (I haven't, this is just an example for the question), just for the sake of this example assume you have a MD5 function like this

`void GENERATEMD5(const char *plain, char *out);`

and you would call it like

```
char hashResult[33] = { 0 };//32 + 1 because of null terminator
GENERATEMD5(passwordInputBuffer, hashResult);
memset(passwordInputBuffer, 0, 32);//set password buf back to null
```

Anyone could easily hook this `GERERATEMD5()` function and simply print out the parameters as they are passed to the function. Example

```
void md5FuncHook(const char *plain, char *out)
{
    md5Hook(plain, out);

    console::print("Plain: %s - Hash: %s", plain, out);
}
```

I was thinking about it and there was only one way I could come up with detecting if a function is hooked (assuming they have hooked the function via modifying the function's first few instructions). And that would be to check the first few bytes of the function then confirm that they are what they are supposed to be.
Example, if we know the first few bytes of the function `GERERATEMD5()` are

```
int GERERATEMD5_Function_bytes_0 = 0x12341234;//just random bytes for the example
int GERERATEMD5_Function_bytes_1 = 0x12341234;//just random bytes for the example
int GERERATEMD5_Function_bytes_2 = 0x12341234;//just random bytes for the example
int GERERATEMD5_Function_bytes_3 = 0x12341234;//just random bytes for the example
```

Then we could do something like this

```
void checkIfGENERATEMD5HasBeenHooked()
{
    int GERERATEMD5_Function_bytes_0 = 0x12341234;//just random bytes for the example
    int GERERATEMD5_Function_bytes_1 = 0x12341234;//just random bytes for the example
    int GERERATEMD5_Function_bytes_2 = 0x12341234;//just random bytes for the example
    int GERERATEMD5_Function_bytes_3 = 0x12341234;//just random bytes for the example

    int readGENERATEMD5FunctionBytes0, readGENERATEMD5FunctionBytes1, readGENERATEMD5FunctionBytes2, readGENERATEMD5FunctionBytes3;
    memcpy(&readGENERATEMD5FunctionBytes0, (char *)(&GENERATEMD5 + 0x00), 0x04);
    memcpy(&readGENERATEMD5FunctionBytes1, (char *)(&GENERATEMD5 + 0x04), 0x04);
    memcpy(&readGENERATEMD5FunctionBytes2, (char *)(&GENERATEMD5 + 0x08), 0x04);
    memcpy(&readGENERATEMD5FunctionBytes3, (char *)(&GENERATEMD5 + 0x0C), 0x04);

    if(GERERATEMD5_Function_bytes_0 == readGENERATEMD5FunctionBytes0 && GENERATEMD5_Function_bytes_1 == readGENERATEMD5FunctionBytes1 && GENERATEMD5_Function_bytes_2 == readGENERATEMD5FunctionBytes2 && GENERATEMD5_Function_bytes_3 == readGENERATEMD5FunctionBytes3)
    {
        //our GENERATEMD5() function is clean
    }
    else
    {
        //hook detected or some other form of function modification detected
    }
}
```

But with everything I have tried this just never seems to work. The issue I'm assuming is coming from where I read the bytes of the function itself, like the calls to memcpy aren't actually reading the bytes located at `&GENERATEMD5 + OFFSET`. Am I just doing something wrong? Or is there a better/different way of doing what I'm trying to accomplish? (btw, yes I know there are many other hooking methods attackers may use when hooking your functions other than what I've described above and just in general many other ways to get a hold of your sensitive information from your executable, but this question has nothing to do with any of that so please just focus on the question rather than just saying something along the lines of "doing this is pointless" or "there are easy ways to bypass this", etc...)

Comment: What is the platform and how the "never seems to work" manifests?

Comment: You obviously got the parentheses wrong, it would have to be `reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&GENERATEMD5) + 0x04` as the +4 is apparently measured in bytes.

Comment: There's also another issue here. You have to be familiar with the target assembly language if you want to do serious work on hooking and unhooking, but you clearly aren't able to study the generated code for the example given. And the function above will generate some quite simple assembly.

Comment: @MSalters Half my program is written directly with ASM.. The machine I'm working on runs POWER5 32bit, I've been working with PPC for years.. And what are you talking about? The + 0x04 takes us to the next 'line of instructions', each 'line' of instructions on my machine is 4 bytes in length (bcuz as the title clearly states "32bit machine"), For example to load the value 1 into the lower 16 bits of register 3 we would do something like `li r3, 1`, then that converted to raw bytes would be 0x38600001. And why are you even commenting on this question? You're clearly are NOT qualified to answer.

Comment: @MSalters hahahah you're funny. "you clearly aren't able to study the generated code ", bro it takes me two seconds to pop my exe into IDA and examine the disassembly.... Everything in my question was just as an example to explain the logic behind what im trying to do. The main issue here just seems to be that you haven't understood my question AT ALL - maybe it's just above your level, go and try answering some other questions that you have the knowledge to answer. This one might be too much for ya ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have done this.  The problem is the loader will modify the code during relocation so you cannot rely on the operand fields being the same value every time.  In my case I used a disassembly library and did a hash on only the opcode bytes.  I used BASTARD to do disassembly at runtime but that project is long dead.  I think there are better options now.

In principle you could probably write the target function in such a way that relocation fixups wouldn't happen, but that's going to be more trouble than it is worth.